# Provisioning profile "Developer profile" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution" : person's name(key number)

Tags: swift, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, ios-app-signing

I am trying to upload an app that was created by my team and I am getting this error :

> **Provisioning profile "Developer profile" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution" : person's name(key number)**

I tried creating and downloading new certificate, a multiple times, but its showing the same error.

Is there any issue if the certificate is of distribution type and not development type, thus preventing to upload the app in test flight?

Comment: You'll need to update the "Developer Profile" and include the mentioned certificate at https://developer.apple.com/account.
You might also want to check if you have same certificate multiple times in your Mac OS Keychain app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can verify the following to troubleshoot your issue:

1. Verify that this certificate is actually an "iOS Distribution" certificate (https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)
2. Double check the bundle id of the certificate and compare it with your app on xCode. They should be the same. Also note the team this certificate is registered to.
3. Go to xCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Select your account -> Select correct team. Then click "Manage Certificates" and ensure the Distribution certificate is listed there.
4. Also ensure that the step 3. certificate doesn't have an error like "Private Key Missing" or something else.
5. Go to Build Settings -> General in xCode (Signing Configs in new xCode) and verify the correct team is selected (the one you noted in 2)

Comment: there is a "Missing Private key", how to sort that out?

Comment: Ok. When your distribution profile was first created, apple provides you with a private key for that certificate (this is a one time download and whoever created the profile should have it). You will have to obtain it and install it in your machine keychain. Or if there are other Mac machines in your workplace that builds the same app, they will have the private key in their keychain which you can export.